# Sort All feature in the Back end.(MySql & Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sorting

I am trying to find the best way to implement sort all feature in my application,where i would like to do a ascending and descending on the UI (ExtJs).It has 25 records to be displayed every time and the user can use 50 or 100 records from the UI Opition.

Since there is an existing functionality there in the application,but it does the sorting ASC or DESC on the give list of 25,50,100 records not on all the given records from the DB.

As per few suggestion available online,some said let the hibernate handle it,some said let the back-end handle it.

But i see the approach little more complex as the application for this derives data from lot of different table, so we are doing a sort right now on the one field rest we are loading the object graph later to improve performance.

So if you have any insight that how we can have an out of box approach it would be really insightful for me

I am using Hibernate for ORM,Spring Container and MySql as database.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

While Hibernate is great for managing entity state transitions, it's not my first choice for pagination or aggregation.

Sorting 25 million records in memory is not efficient, so you'd better use SQL for that with a proper index. If you can make a framework choice you could rely on [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/seek-clause/) for this task. Even if you can't choose JOOQ you can still employ a native query and project the results to DTOs.

While returning Entities is great when you plan to change them (Create Update Delete), DTOs yield better performance for Read operations. You can even achieve an index-only-scan if you play your cards right.

Comment: Hi, @Vlad thank you for your prompt reply,yes i was think of having a SQL query to sort all the records and give it to the Hibernate to make necessary changes that it can send back to UI( depending upon how much records should be displayed in my case its 25 ,50 ,100 through ExtJs) but i was thinking of using 2nd level cache or criteria to limit achieve that same.Can you be kind enough to show some example here with Native Query (as JOOQ would not be possible to be accommodated in our project right now)?

Comment: The second level cache only stores entities by id, it won't help you when you do the actual query. If you follow the JOOQ like I sent you, you will see you can do it with native SQL as well. Using OFFSET you need to keep the last max processed value, and limit the next batch. With seek you need to keep the last max processed id too, to make the SELECT faster.

Comment: Thank you @Vlad i will try to use JOOQ in my application and see if it can fulfill my expectations.

Comment: If you consider I answered your question you can mark it as answered.